# Strange behavior in a function that moves items inside an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, function, pointers

I have a function that gets called like this

```
arraypointer = move(arraypointer, item, remove_location, move_location)
```

(It calls itself inside another function where `arraypointer` gets used a lot.)

So if I have an array like this

```
1 2 3 0 4 5 6
```

and I call

```
arraypointer = move(arraypointer, 0, 3, 0)
```

It will return

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Here is the code

```
int* move(const int arrz[], const int mvalue, const int rlocation, const int mlocation) {
    static int uselessarray[7] = { 0 };
    uselessarray[0] = arrz[0];
    uselessarray[1] = arrz[1];
    uselessarray[2] = arrz[2];
    uselessarray[3] = arrz[3];
    uselessarray[4] = arrz[4];
    uselessarray[5] = arrz[5];
    uselessarray[6] = arrz[6];

    static int returnarray[7];
    returnarray[0] = 1;
    int i = 0; int j = 0;

    
    
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (i == mlocation) {
            j++;
            returnarray[mlocation] = mvalue;
        }
        if (i == rlocation) {
        }
        else {
            returnarray[j] = uselessarray[i];
            //returnarray[j] = arrz[i];
            j++;
        }
        
    }
    return returnarray;
}
```

If I don't initialize the `uselessarray` and copy the data from `arrz`. Then when I change `returnarray` it also changez `arrz`. Even though `arrz` is a constant and I'm in no way asking for it to be changed. It does exactly what I want with the code I pasted above. But I'm trying to figure out why on earth I need the `uselessarray` in the first place. Why can't it just use the array I am originally passing to it. Why does it change when I'm not asking it to change?

I tried

1. Adding sizes to `arrz`
2. Making `arrz` `static` instead of `const`
3. making `returnarray` not `static` (that breaks it even more)
4. Giving `returnarray` initial values using `= { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 }`

Nothing other than declaring the `uselessarray` works. What is going on here?

Comment: Your array has 6 elements, but you're trying to access 7.

Comment: What is seems like is a simple copy of a value (into temporary variable), followed by a [memory move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove), followed by copying the (temporary) value to its final place.

Comment: @dbush The example had 6. But in the actual code its 7. Sorry about that confusion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I honestly don't know how to use a memory move in this situation. You are probably right that it would be more appropriate.

Is there a youtube video or something I can look at. A lot of these programming references people post speak in a language I don't understand.

Comment: Are you sure this is the *exact* code that gives you the result you posted?  Because I get "2 3 0 0" for the first 4 elements.  This seems to be in line with the given code.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run and get the same results you do.

Comment: If I swap the last two arguments, then I get your results.  Same also if I remove `uselessarray`.

Comment: @NickMatveev What language are you using, C or C++?  Please choose one.

Comment: @dbush I messed up which one is rlocation and which one is mlocation. I went ahead and fixed it

Comment: I suspect your actual problem is in code you *haven't* shown us.  This is where a MRE comes into play.  Also, first try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: @dbush I'm using windows 10. I think you're right. It's almost certainly some sort of memory malfunction. I am working with Visual Studio 2019. It has a very good CPU profiler. Has helped me identify a lot of problems. There is probably a way to do the same analysis using Visual Studio. What is it called?

Comment: @NickMatveev I'll be the odd one here, but your definition of what you want to do is confusing to me.   Calling your function simply `move` does not convey what it actually does -- maybe `copy_and_swap` or something like that -- if it were simple to understand, this should be no more than 3 lines of code, even if that.  Whatever you want to do, this looks like simple `std::swap` and `std::copy` calls (this is why you should post the language you're using -- C++ has these functions).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am using C++ as my language. Was not aware of the swap and copy commands. I just called the function "move" because previously I had one function remove the item then yet another function add the item in a certain location. I decided to consolidate it all into one function. How would this work with swap and copy? I don't always want to move the items to the first position in the array.

Comment: please post your main that shows it not working.   It works for me, both with and without uselessarray and does not disrupt the original array.

Comment: @mevets I don't mind pasting the code. But I can't figure out how to do it without murdering the formatting. Even the <code> tag doesn't work.

Comment: Cut+Paste it in, then in the window, select the whole portion that is code.   With it highlighted, click the {} icon.

Comment: @mevets Code is too big. Is there somewhere else I can paste it. I tried making a github account but I can't figure out how to just add a simple code in there. It wants to do repository lol.

Comment: @mevets Ok finally figured out github. https://github.com/nick050183/pokerstuff/blob/main/poker.cpp

You can see the function get called on like 473

Answer (score 1):

A function that would work for your example could look something like this:

```
void move(int arrz[], const int mvalue, const int rlocation, const int mlocation)
{
    // Get a copy of the value to "move"
    int value = arrz[mlocation];

    // Move (part) of the array one step to the right
    memmove(&arrz[rlocation + 1], &arrz[rlocation], (mlocation - rlocation) * sizeof(int));

    // And copy the value to its destination place
    arrz[rlocation] = value;
}
```

<sub>[[Working example here](https://godbolt.org/z/h3Mc37)]</sub>

Note that this code do the changes in-place in the original array. If you need to create a new array and return, then I suggest you pass the new array in as a pointer to its first element.

While this works for the example shown in the question, it might not work for other cases unknown to us.

Comment: Going to give this a try. Give me a few a minutes. Thank you btw.

Comment: Ok so I just looked at the code. I don't always want to move to the first element. Sometimes I will replace say value that is in 5 with value in 3

So like

1 2 4 5 3 6 7

move(arrz, 3, 5, 3)

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

It needs to be removed from the 5th location and added to the 3rd location. While keeping the rest of the array in tact.

Answer (score 1):

To test your function, I added this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pa(int *a, int n) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                printf("%d%s", a[i], i == n-1 ? "\n" : ", ");
        }
}
int main() {
        int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6 };
        int *p;
        p = move(a, 0, 3, 0);
        pa(a, 7);
        pa(p, 7);
        return 0;
}
```

And, no surprise it works as expected.   However, what you are doing (from you github dump) is more like this:

```
int main() {
            int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6 };
            int *p;
            p = move(a, 0, 3, 0);
            pa(a, 7);
            pa(p, 7);
            p = move(p, 1, 2, 3);
            pa(p, 7);
            return 0;
    }
```

Note that the second call to move provides p, which is the static returned from the first call to move.   This is the source of your problems.

ps:  you should review the rules for posting on so.

Comment: Huge thanks. I will review the rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a solution for this problem, taking into account security concerns. As a general approach, the original sequence content and address are not intervened in subprograms. I have considered a few error elements that can occur in the solution I develop. The following link can be used to test the program: [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/e#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tENwDMpLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiIAOwAGUgAdUBUJ1Wj1DEzNLAKC1OjsHZyM3Dx9FZUxVEIYCZmICMONTCzSVWNps3IJ4p1d3L18FHLyCiOLGyurE5PqASkVUA2JkDgByAHoAKgnxbwBBAGoJ%2BYABF2I8TCoZgE4ASQJ5vAV5ggRMeb9iVGBiZiMThGYDo2YAa0xj0/OFZipzl9oeD8BmEZXmqCo82YUOItwAngA6GYLaZzRYrZgGU4kHYMbAAJR0s0c8zx0mwABVxDpzOIAByeanccTSbzIxbspbLdBPc47bycBHeSQIyTCzicsbI6WScz2ZCGLDzcTmHSNfCoBEIFXYGVy2gKgxKlVqgjoVh4FxanV6%2BWKvmqxrrUTW8y6ubIsZe%2Bb7Q7HAxKdDzGjEB7fPBGPzsRrBkj3CFQnl%2BHJgojzABuuTh9mAMPh8yCAC8PkiPbKsFR7OdZvj8bMAJoAfQYuwAWth5oyPXNJqiUSs1hstt49gcAO54ViseZueYBzBBtOPbTsAuoIzndxXYifR7PZhw8HIZCDQ60MMXK43O6llFSuZaYzzLckPRYaWeWTd7ZUTGsAjRscKoACLzL4OwQSOkHbN6jioM%2BsIkEeJ6wguZ4Xpc1y3EY0ojgoAxDJgsywge2CIaGIHzAAtJwpDQTs3oMARwx5ge8zoKgHy0GAIwHAE9gHGmIiJugxAfAot47FgjT2E8ITEfCZHbsq5igVRkikMqI7esBHxqLQcl0Kxh4cVxPF8agAknPBwnMOgoniZJI6sKgLBlBSuTAJgBBKUhlFUZY0HejYrmGeeTReQcmAAB7DAuxy5PmRaYE52xoH4cK%2BRRqnUbwWnbPR2ljPMegZQhymPMcrkoWJ6CpclWUqWpACsmmFQVRXzApbHJQlYnzLQqBRQAjgYbCSZ4wEql%2BsyelMnIDusmw7BSZzlUhG4KD8Xl%2BpeAloWmXwFmaW7HWJdzWQWCCoGOF4sPOC3tQmR0vqG9h3XQ%2BHsLe6LLH4uQXTsQTALQT5HBer0DbUoaecYWgED9Ez3rM6aWUGr0ABIiOa7gQGeBzA6D9w9B%2BM1AxOBDIAgeOE0%2BJPfuIn64R1aXMEoa6DMM3WZeRIDM9BVCXAJVA0ydsJtZIkhMZz5yJWxpkKNxvEXJZ9CXbZ9liVtSKS/MJPmGTUFG9sayYG8024bNxssOz0n6WF3NZXzDPG4LzoECLx1YOLyqS7pMkGWCcsmZxivmSrVlCeedkOdrUiSHrFsuyzpvmwblvQTb5wuW5IQecQkVO/zrtC/QnvqluEuSCFudGRF3nPrFmDxcZBZ4MWOsJ/rhsszsqevEnVtWyzWfzOlPPbs7w8C6XHui97ZC%2B5IpWHpDlXIYMtWd4n6fJ3350D7vQ%2BZ2z4bFkXe8jm7wvz5XS/c23xZ9ecg0jWNrDb93xcpwfg/fxWf4CBT3atfMut8fbx1mOeAwtBXiDTHOeNebMN6oTqvHHePdoL9z/lBSaGcRwxUIHjbAAANXYFJGwADFZi7BsAAVXxB2L%2BHo8HdlmL2BaqwlrDm2AwAwLhMLXnuKcJ4Y9hKznnEGEMBZfjnAILcWgCgAh5HBJCI6aB6DwyqpCWyJFEScP%2BthfKJA8DAFkqwB%2Bq1zgaIIPDVRF4TFmIMhYvRrdwb/S2gdeCR1BFGLZo9Y2OwNax0%2BPBWcAIgQgl5HVUk8o5FrWDuCdYTi2AP3cWzQMl0vgBN7nhfhviLrIPjhomMVklglIIPHTShAEqa3ElCbQY86C2LViwWgr8ZzWOXF5NBaIuSGMBiOLWIICAP12LuWWrixxnH6kdYZ/52JPGhBOKcnTjokAXIjFYAz7hA3bucfEmx3ChIvMlexR1HHmPYngMSqgSD6L6dsgGuyhk1zCvMQ5fwdxZLWvXA4OcwpbL%2Bs8/KRg3lgk%2Bccn55xojBCMs9NaPIciXXCagdMaF3pHWDkCsSBBBjnh2IcvFxBFEXnResSstdzxoCVHgSEg11qhmqoMY4mK1oFKMIjZGVkjBoswHjCp%2BN0SCsuc47m1S1blM%2BgceZoy9GaUFVZZKCrpVCuIOCkIKrFEHB5Rqoy9NZpMzYTsOleNRWpNcSBSijg6E2BsInBmRrp4EPIljFcuMOaEUduRDB/NWHHxHKa%2BYsqH5Wpyjau1Drp5OugpjbG7BiB4ztrJMo3rlLMOjVNY1gbPZgtCmCG0OUzkGogjG42cb3WJvmAC9ynlvKNQzaWrNAbthBprHWJsLZ2wqR0I/c4JbcGYJdduN1OMq0NR9Y23BzbmZemKlYxZyK2UwsCHC88HjMlGV0cAOGatwZuBzPMXl6LenDxDXo8QzVpBgWVM1UClFzUuPhJe69eaqW3qmkfWd3oF2Vh3FFPwRwMDnARSB5JVzEng3ShsRc3i1oOFuti5mQaNxGGQBlPGUgABs57n1XuDXqglMh5icA/RLLDj7uYvoI/mkIZH5h4zfe8qiNH309HRMlCEeMrLsfY2G0CEb7UDoKmWlmFax0CtQBlBtOCRMzu/HO%2BYC6lAaKDIYg4oGkmmIg64qDUmYPQoGpgRDejUoocwGhjDvscMfBGVR/DTGC3EdI5e4C5HKMXoc4R3216XN3s0njdtDZmxtg7Cxxj3m5Akb1jFpYnHPY8Zi/x%2BYgmo2lqHdscTCbJPScnbJxm8mz3eXxcGQBgE/7%2Brmn2X6g5lojgALLMHegABSvNhThuL8WEuKyS443hDhqPZW1i64MFAGGPOJKgIIuXIh5U12geNUZ4CDCW0TVkPN4evUFztoWP1NWVJ%2BEjmkNLzEsGBTSeVWrzCwwdz9PdFNQMPPtYg6L6B0cOmtR9biw7K2YBN5MzAXCrmkQgUxCACwZEGIQQ8wJiDRBLPg1tatcMHmo9tkL3bXP7cZte/rBXZOKYXQhpJ3t5grOnLORoGygxsvBok6RtiA65lh/DiSiOYGEwxXu7QMV9tsi/UVYqvpydrMkbGUMaAYG2Il2cZArxD3LvF9W1AUmnLDysq9N8mACfegAOqTgp%2BcMXaZMLpmW5uH1VMMjy5dIjzXwH9vHv5VplJT6DyaRR3CTS6Ou3YE0ud07vqFM/rWtwB4z52AbjVppxJIvUUnsM6h%2B5IktbHGme4eJ5xOCNG/cVdIUeNODcmfmUbRAt7zAAPJfBhq4/PWiycG7WckhABNQdUFsae3PPoi/9THMghlkNFdjYEcNowmlZ4fU0fQbRF5EkfesZ9fQKVkOe3t8aVSlFfwjMAmlwd38QzcZ59FPnKlr32CwMfk0XVazBd96fnzchz%2B8%2BE%2Bl7%2BOxZ6e3jht1H%2BGpDNQMB%2BiAL7M1OgJejoJUs1OAVUmeBfppN/nCNRk/pfnekHi2tBB/phpLJ7tRn/gAa5kAX/qAZAbQNAUgR7rZv%2BPZmfkfntlOr3JVtOojp1iSvMKQuQs2HQjoDoNgAwAwBVoViMH0KwCACMM1CMKQKYCMN4OIagCIToHIFFvhDLL7OYJwOIUAlIYIX0K8CAM1L4MISMNwOIZIdIaQLISMOIQoCAL4BodIX0HALAEgDFJDmXuQJQJ5AoM1iIMoAwNdAgiIWoaQGgJGJOGFF4Q4KwL4TdCYeIcEYBgmiAMAJwMKEEeuPEe4BXliFEf4ZoVYNFBkMRMAFYRYXkRkNkPgJIeITQPQEwGwBwDwPwIIMIKICgAoTIEIJaFYZAH0FJmUMUZYcxPUYoGaPYOET4X4ZIYEWOLcH4AEYIUICIWIRISIaYeYdFHSFhlRFhmHsAMeCRt4KKKwfkSeGXgxrgIQH5LKJwOxvITIHIOoSsVoaQDoXoQsYYcYY8WYSIZYdYaQLYU8QYZIB8bkeYQ8ZoT0H0OSkEBoNwEAA%3D)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/// It is used for the simplest form of adaptation to varying array sizes.
#define ARRAY_SIZE 7

/**
 * @brief   It will be used to handle some errors that may occur in the program.
 */
enum errorCode
{
    faultless = 0,                  // No error occurred in the program
    sourceArrayError = -1,          // Source array doesn't point to an address.
    destinationArrayError = -2,     // Destination array doesn't point to an address.
    locationTargetError = -3,       // Location target exceeds array size.
    copyError = -4,                 // Copy error has occurred.
    sizeError = -5,                 // Array sizes are not equal.
};

/**
 * @brief   The error message is printed to the stderr stream to show the cause
 *          of the error in the console.
 * @param   signum is the error number argument.
 */
void errorHandler( int signum )
{
    switch( signum )
    {
        case sourceArrayError:
            fprintf( stderr, "Source array doesn't point to an address." );
            break;

        case destinationArrayError:
            fprintf( stderr, "Destination array doesn't point to an address." );
            break;

        case locationTargetError:
            fprintf( stderr, "Location target exceeds array size." );
            break;

        case copyError:
            fprintf( stderr, "Copy error has occurred." );
            break;

        case sizeError:
            fprintf( stderr, "Array sizes are not equal." );
            break;

        default:
            fprintf( stderr, "An unknown error has occurred." );
            break;
    }

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

/**
 * @brief   Subprogram that can be used for safe transport of the contents of an array.
 * @param   originalArray The content of the originalArray array is passed to the program as
 *          an address to be manipulated. Since the array originalArray is passed to the
 *          subprogram as "const int * const", its address and content cannot be changed.
 * @param   resultArray Is the array where the result data will be stored.
 * @param   size Refers to the size of the original directory.
 * @param   rLocation Refers to the target location.
 * @param   mLocation Refers to the position of the data to be moved in the array.
 * @return  Returns the verification code if no error occurs in the program.
 */
int move( const int * const originalArray, int * const resultArray, const int size, const int rLocation, const int mLocation )
{
    /// If the array doesn't point to an address, terminate the program.
    if( originalArray == NULL )
    {
        errorHandler( sourceArrayError );
    }

    /// If the array doesn't point to an address, terminate the program.
    if( resultArray == NULL )
    {
        errorHandler( destinationArrayError );
    }

    /// Terminate the program if the position of the element to be read in the array is outside the array dimensions.
    if( mLocation >= size )
    {
        errorHandler( locationTargetError );
    }

    /// Terminate the program if the array size argument passed to the subprogram is greater than the current array size.
    if( ARRAY_SIZE < size )
    {
        errorHandler( sizeError );
    }

    /// The data in the position passed on an argument is being moved.
    /// originalArray should only be used as a rvalue in the program.
    resultArray[ 0 ] = originalArray[ mLocation ];

    /// The first episode of the original array is copied to the new array.
    if( memcpy( &resultArray[ rLocation + 1 ], &originalArray[ rLocation ], ( mLocation - rLocation ) * sizeof( int ) ) == NULL )
    {
        errorHandler( copyError );
    }

    /// The second part of the original array is copied to the new array.
    if( memcpy( &resultArray[ mLocation + 1 ], &originalArray[ mLocation + 1 ], ( ARRAY_SIZE - ( mLocation + 1 ) ) * sizeof( int ) ) == NULL )
    {
        errorHandler( copyError );
    }

    return faultless;
}

/**
 * @brief   Main Program
 * @return  Returns 0 if the program is successful.
 */
int main( void )
{
    int originalArray[ ARRAY_SIZE ] = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6 };
    /// Any intervention to the original array isn't acceptable for high security purposes.

    int resultArray[ ARRAY_SIZE ] = { 0 };
    /// The new order will be stored in this array for testing purposes.

    unsigned int index = 0;
    /// It will be used for counter checking in the for loop.

    int errorCode;
    /// Will be used to provide error checking.

    errorCode = move( originalArray, resultArray, ARRAY_SIZE,  0, 3 );
    /// The 4 th element of the array will be moved to the memory address where the 1st
    /// element of the array is stored. Other array elements will be right shifted.

    /// If there was no error in the subprogram, print the contents of the array to the console.
    if( errorCode == faultless )
    {
        for( index = 0 ; index < ARRAY_SIZE ; ++index )
        {
            printf( "originalArray[ %u ]: %d\t\t", index, originalArray[ index ] );

            printf( "resultArray[ %u ]: %d\n", index, resultArray[ index ] );
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```